# Add Button To Add Student Django Admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So below is my admin section, what im trying to do is create a button near my drop down list to add a student to a classroom.( Button in screenshot is where it should be placed) The dropdown list is populated from another table called students , however my field students in class will be a list of all the students in the class. Basically im making a roster. The goal is later when i query that classroom list i return all the students in that class. Right now the field students in class is just set to a charfield, not sure if that is correct. Appreciate the help.

[[image: Admin Screen Shot[1]]

```
class TeacherClass(models.Model):
teacher_class_id = models.CharField(primary_key = True , default = "", max_length = 50, unique = True)
teacher_class_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
teacher_id = models.ForeignKey(Teachers, on_delete = models.PROTECT, default = "")
student_id = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete = models.PROTECT, default= "")
students_in_class = models.CharField(max_length=500, default = "")

class Meta:
    abstract = False
    verbose_name = "Teacher Class"

def __str__(self):
    return self.teacher_class_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you should look into using a ManyToMany field instead of a single foreign key field. Take a look at the documentation below:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/